# Topology on $X$ using topology on $ X × Y $

Tags: general-topology

Suppose there is topology on set $X × Y$. This is not product topology using topology on $X$ and topology on $Y$, all we know is $X$ and $Y$ are just sets. Then can we put topology on $X$?

Comment: Any set can be given the discrete topology, so yes. Is there a further condition that you wish to impose?

Comment: Ya..I mean some unique natural topology on $X$ using topology on space $X×Y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\tau$ be the topology on $X\times Y$, and let $\pi:X\times Y\to X:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto x$ be the projection to the first factor. Let $\tau_X=\{U\subseteq X:\pi^{-1}[U]\in\tau\}$. If $U,V\in\tau_X$, then

$$\pi^{-1}[U\cap V]=\pi^{-1}[U]\cap\pi^{-1}[V]\in\tau\;,$$

so $U\cap V\in\tau_X$. Similarly, if $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\tau_X$, then

$$\pi^{-1}\left[\bigcup\mathscr{U}\right]=\bigcup\{\pi^{-1}[U]:U\in\mathscr{U}\}\in\tau\;,$$

so $\bigcup\mathscr{U}\in\tau_X$. Clearly $\varnothing,X\in\tau_X$, so $\tau_X$ is a topology on $X$ determined by the given topology $\tau$ on $X\times Y$.

Note that $\tau_X$ may not be very nice. For instance, for $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ let

$$B_\alpha=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:x+y=\alpha\}\;,$$

and let $\mathscr{B}=\{B_\alpha:\alpha\in\Bbb R\}$; $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for a topology $\tau$ on $\Bbb R^2$, and it’s not hard to check that in this case $\tau_{\Bbb R}=\{\varnothing,\Bbb R\}$, the indiscrete topology on $\Bbb R$.

> As an exercise you might find it instructive to try to prove that $\left\langle\Bbb R^2,\tau\right\rangle$ is homeomorphic to $X\times Y$, where $X$ is $\Bbb R$ with the discrete topology, and $Y$ is $\Bbb R$ with the indiscrete topology.

Comment: I think the map which will take the slanted lines $x+y=\alpha$ to vertical lines $x=\alpha$ will give homeomorphism

Comment: I was wondering if we can put following topology on X. Take open set from space $X×Y$ and then collect all the first coordinates and then take it as open set. For example if $X=\{x_1,x_2\}$ and $Y=\{y_1,y_2\}$ and $\tau_{X×Y}=\{{X×Y}, {(x_1, y_1),\phi}\}$, then my topology on $X$ is $\{X,(x_1),\phi\}$ and the way you said will give topology $\{{X, \phi}\}$.

Comment: @Believer: Yes, the topology that I described is just a $\frac{\pi}4$ rotation of the product topology. // If I understand correctly, you want to define a topology on $X$ by declaring the projection map from $\pi_X:X\times Y\to X$ to be open, so that $\tau_X=\{\pi_X[V]:V\in\tau\}$. Unfortunately you may not get a topology. Let $X=\{0,1,2\},Y=\{0,1\},U=\{0,1\}\times\{0\},V=\{1,2\}\times\{1\}$, and $\tau=\varnothing,U,V,U\cup V,X\times Y\}$; the projections to $X$ give you the sets $\varnothing,\{0,1\},\{1,2\}$, and $X$, which isn’t a topology: it doesn’t include $\{0,1\}\cap\{1,2\}$.

Comment: Thank you for counterexample !

Comment: @Believer: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

There is a natural surjective map from $X \times Y$ to $X$, namely the projection function $p(x,y)=x$.

So, it seems natural to take the quotient topology on $X$ induced by the given topology on $X \times Y$ and the function $p$.

Briefly, this quotient topology is defined to be the strongest topology on $X$ such that $p$ is a continuous function (with respect to the given topology on $X \times Y)$. In more detail, this quotient topology on $X$ is defined so that a subset $U \subset X$ is open *if and only if* $p^{-1}(U) = U \times Y \subset X \times Y$ is open.

By the way, when using given topologies on $X$ and $Y$ and the product topology on $X \times Y$, this is the way that you can *recover* the given topology on $X$: it is the quotient of the product topology on $X \times Y$ with respect to the projection function $p : X \times Y \to X$.

Also, there's nothing special about Cartesian products in this discussion. Given any topological space $Z$, any set $X$, and any surjective function $p : Z \to X$, the quotient topology on $X$ is a natural topology associated to $Z$ and $p$.